# lvalue reference became invalid after passing through an identity function

Tags: c++, c++11

Would someone explain why the reference became invalid after going through an "identity" function, `foo1`?  Isn't an "address" to `A` is passed into and returned by `foo1`?

```
struct A {
    A(int x) : x_(x) {}
    int x_;
};

int main() {

    function<const A&(const A& r)> foo1 = [](const A& r) { 
        return r;
    };

    vector<A> vec{1, 2, 3};
    cout << foo1(vec[0]).x_ << endl;   // RUNTIME ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

How does the problem line differ from:

```
const A& r = vec[0];
const A& r1 = r;
```

Comment: I tried with vs2015 and your code works well.

Comment: @alangab didn't work in VS2013.

Comment: I thought that lambda was called `fool`. That was foolish.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Think you mean it was foo1ish.

Comment: maybe you should specify what "RUNTIME ERROR" you get...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is your lambda. It doesn't do what you think it does:

```
function<const A&(const A& r)> foo1 = [](const A& r) { 
//                                               ~~~~~~
    return r;
};
```

Note that there's no trailing return type. That means that it's automatically deduced. Deduction never gives you a reference type, so this lambda returns an `A`, not an `A const&`. That returned temporary `A` is then bound to the return `A const&` of `function`'s `operator()`. That temporary is not lifetime-extended. But the time we finish calling `foo1()`, we have a dangling reference to that temporary `A`. This is undefined behavior, which I guess with your compiler, gave you a helpful runtime error.

To fix this, you need to explicitly specify the return type:

```
function<const A&(const A& r)> foo1 = [](const A& r) -> A const& { 
    return r;
};
```

But even this is dangerous, since you can still pass a *temporary* `A` into this function and get a dangling reference out. No real way around that one.

---

The ease of falling into this trap is also [LWG Issue 2813](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2813)

Comment: Ugh, that's a nasty trap :(

Comment: Could also be useful to use `->auto&&` to preserve at least some of return type deduction.

Answer (score 12):

While your `function` object returns `const A&` the lambda you provide it does not. It's return type is deduced from the return statement, which is deduced to be `A`. Try adding an explicit return type like this instead.

```
function<const A&(const A& r)> foo1 = [](const A& r) -> const A& { 
    return r;
};
```